# Running R script with RSript doesn't seem to save workspace

Tags: r, rscript

I am running RSCript with the --save command.  When the script finishes, if I then run 'R' I do not workspace variables of script.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including `save.image()` at the end of your script. This will create a .Rdata file in your working directory that will save all the variables that were created by your script. To load that workspace the next time you open R, you could type in `load("present/working/directory/.Rdata")`

Hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: So how is this different then the --save argument to RScript?

Answer (score 1):

The Rscript works for me. Need to use the command, la, to see the generated file .RData

`Rscript --save test.R`